# Angular2 app works on initial load, but hot-reloading throws `The selector "app" did not match any elements`

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

SOLVED: The issue turned out to be something to do with my `package.json`. I checked it and it was somehow an older one without all of my scripts and dependencies that are in the one I linked in the post. However, I was still able to run the scripts and launch it initially and it all worked fine. Somehow it was reading from two different `package.json` files and I assume when the hot reloading happened, it was reading from the old one?... I deleted updated the old one, ran `npm install` and everything is working fine now.

---

On initial page load, the site runs fine and loads the proper data, but when I try to change some of the content, and check to see if hot-reloading is working, it throws these errors.

```
Error: The selector "app" did not match any elements
    at DomRenderer.selectRootElement (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:1129:1), <anonymous>:196:23) [angular]
    at DebugDomRenderer.selectRootElement (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:2480:1), <anonymous>:47:56) [angular]
    at selectOrCreateRenderHostElement (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:748:1), <anonymous>:509:32) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:13:16) [angular]
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:2529:1), <anonymous>:121:21) [angular]
```

Since it's loading on the initial load, I'll just post my `package.json` and `webpack.config.js`.

Here's my `package.json`. I'm running `npm run watch` in one console and `npm run start:hmr` in another console.

```
{
  "name": "site-pinger",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf node_modules doc dist && npm cache clean",
    "clean-install": "npm run clean && npm install",
    "clean-start": "npm run clean-install && npm start",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --progress --profile",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --progress --profile --bail",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "lint": "tslint --force \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "e2e-live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "karma start",
    "posttest": "remap-istanbul -i coverage/json/coverage-final.json -o coverage/html -t html",
    "test-watch": "karma start --no-single-run --auto-watch",
    "ci": "npm run e2e && npm run test",
    "docs": "typedoc --options typedoc.json src/app/app.component.ts",
    "start": "npm run server",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server -- --hot",
    "postinstall": "npm run webdriver-update"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.39",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.50",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.17",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "karma": "1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

---

Here's my `webpack.config.js`

```
// Helper: root() is defined at the bottom
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

// Webpack Plugins
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

/**
 * Env
 * Get npm lifecycle event to identify the environment
 */
var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTestWatch = ENV === 'test-watch';
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || isTestWatch;
var isProd = ENV === 'build:watch';

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {
  /**
   * Config
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
   * This is the object where all configuration gets set
   */
  var config = {};

  /**
   * Devtool
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
   * Type of sourcemap to use per build type
   */
  if (isProd) {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
  }
  else if (isTest) {
    config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
  }
  else {
    config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
  }

  if (!isTest) {
    /**
     * Entry
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    config.entry = isTest ? {} : {
      'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
      'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
      'app': './src/main.ts' // our angular app
    };
  }

  /**
   * Output
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
   */
  config.output = isTest ? {} : {
    path: root('dist'),
    publicPath: isProd ? '/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: isProd ? 'js/[name].[hash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
    chunkFilename: isProd ? '[id].[hash].chunk.js' : '[id].chunk.js'
  };

  /**
   * Resolve
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
   */
  config.resolve = {
    // only discover files that have those extensions
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
  };

  var atlOptions = '';
  if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    // awesome-typescript-loader needs to output inlineSourceMap for code coverage to work with source maps.
    atlOptions = 'inlineSourceMap=true&sourceMap=false';
  }

  /**
   * Loaders
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
   * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html
   * This handles most of the magic responsible for converting modules
   */
  config.module = {
    rules: [
      // Support for .ts files.
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader?' + atlOptions, 'angular2-template-loader', '@angularclass/hmr-loader'],
        exclude: [isTest ? /\.(e2e)\.ts$/ : /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/]
      },

      // copy those assets to output
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[hash].[ext]?'
      },

      // Support for *.json files.
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},

      // Support for CSS as raw text
      // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
      // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: root('src', 'app'),
        loader: isTest ? 'null-loader' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader']})
      },
      // all css required in src/app files will be merged in js files
      {test: /\.css$/, include: root('src', 'app'), loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader'},

      // support for .scss files
      // use 'null' loader in test mode (https://github.com/webpack/null-loader)
      // all css in src/style will be bundled in an external css file
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        exclude: root('src', 'app'),
        loader: isTest ? 'null-loader' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']})
      },
      // all css required in src/app files will be merged in js files
      {test: /\.(scss|sass)$/, exclude: root('src', 'style'), loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'},

      // support for .html as raw text
      // todo: change the loader to something that adds a hash to images
      {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader',  exclude: root('src', 'index.html')}
    ]
  };

  if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    // instrument only testing sources with Istanbul, covers ts files
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.ts$/,
      enforce: 'post',
      include: path.resolve('src'),
      loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
      exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/, /\.e2e\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
    });
  }

  if (!isTest || !isTestWatch) {
    // tslint support
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.ts$/,
      enforce: 'pre',
      loader: 'tslint-loader'
    });
  }

  /**
   * Plugins
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
   * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html
   */
  config.plugins = [
    // Define env variables to help with builds
    // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      // Environment helpers
      'process.env': {
        ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    }),

    // Workaround needed for angular 2 angular/angular#11580
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
        root('./src') // location of your src
      ),

    // Tslint configuration for webpack 2
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        /**
         * Apply the tslint loader as pre/postLoader
         * Reference: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
         */
        tslint: {
          emitErrors: false,
          failOnHint: false
        },
        /**
         * Sass
         * Reference: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader
         * Transforms .scss files to .css
         */
        sassLoader: {
          //includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss")]
        },
        /**
         * PostCSS
         * Reference: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core
         * Add vendor prefixes to your css
         */
        postcss: [
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 version']
          })
        ]
      }
    })
  ];

  if (!isTest && !isTestWatch) {
    config.plugins.push(
      // Generate common chunks if necessary
      // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html
      // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
      new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
      }),

      // Inject script and link tags into html files
      // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './index.html',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
      }),

      // Extract css files
      // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
      // Disabled when in test mode or not in build mode
      new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'css/[name].[hash].css', disable: !isProd})
    );
  }

  // Add build specific plugins
  if (isProd) {
    config.plugins.push(
      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
      // Only emit files when there are no errors
      new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

      // // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin
      // // Dedupe modules in the output
      // new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

      // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
      // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true, mangle: { keep_fnames: true }}),

      // Copy assets from the public folder
      // Reference: https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: root('src/public')
      }])
    );
  }

  /**
   * Dev server configuration
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver
   * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
   */
  config.devServer = {
    contentBase: './src/public',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    quiet: true,
    stats: 'minimal' // none (or false), errors-only, minimal, normal (or true) and verbose
  };

  return config;
}();

// Helper functions
function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```

---

Adding before and after code as requested by comment.

Before:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

After:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angula'; }
```

Comment: SOLVED: The issue turned out to be something to do with my `package.json`. I checked it and it was somehow an older one without all of my scripts and dependencies that are in the one I linked in the post. However, I was still able to run the scripts and launch it initially and it all worked fine. Somehow it was reading from two different `package.json` files and I assume when the hot reloading happened, it was reading from the old one?... I deleted updated the old one, ran `npm install` and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on selectors, the elements that are rendered in your DOM.

You should be careful about

1. Selector of any component defined in ts file should match with that of in HTML across application.
2. Every component should be declared in the declarations array of particular Module.

Comment: It's just a single opponent within a single module. And it's working on initial load.

Comment: what are your changes?

Comment: Editing a value from displaying "hello angular" to "hello angula"

Comment: update the post with before and after screenshots of the code

Comment: SOLVED: The issue turned out to be something to do with my `package.json`. I checked it and it was somehow an older one without all of my scripts and dependencies that are in the one I linked in the post. However, I was still able to run the scripts and launch it initially and it all worked fine. Somehow it was reading from two different `package.json` files and I assume when the hot reloading happened, it was reading from the old one?... I deleted updated the old one, ran `npm install` and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

For me, for some reason, I was getting the same on hot-reloading and the cause was calling this somewhere in my component:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

...

this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

Once I removed the call to `detectChanges()`, hot-reloading worked again.

I am using Angular 6.0.3.